# Converting complete latex to html

Tags: pandoc, latex2html

I have tried these:
1)latex2html won't work with external packages like paralist
2)pandoc-ruby not generating html correctly, actually not at all
3)ht4tex. I haven't tried it yet. Can I install it without miktex. I am working with basictex.

Comment: You should add a minimal working example, so we can try what  doesn't work. `tex4ht` is included in both Miktex and TeX Live, I don't know anything about Basictex.

Answer (score 1):

All methods that I know result in some loss of latex code. I would suppose your best bet is to run your tex file through pandoc. A simple one-liner would suffice:

`pandoc file.tex -o file.html -t html5`

Comment: extra packages like paralist, are not available to pandoc, that's why these package become useless, and we get unusual html output.